# Text Being Randomly Indented 1 line down

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm having problems with `float: right` in CSS

```css
.herro {float:right;}.isaac {  
padding: 4px;
margin-right:2%;
Margin-left:2%;
background-color: #2E64FE; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); 
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 12px rgba(23, 69, 88, .5);
-webkit-border-radius: 100px;
-moz-border-radius: 100px; 
border-radius: 10px;
}

.dropbtn {
background-color: #2E9AFE;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #2E2EFE;}
```

```html
<div class="isaac" style="padding:5px;">
<img class="left"src="http://www.conway.k12.wa.us/sites/default/files/logov4.png" width="20%">
<div class="herro">A Website by Isaac Sybrandy, Junior Website Craftsman.</div>
<br>
<div class="dropdown" style="float:right; margin-right:32px;">
<button class="dropbtn">Sources</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Isaac</a>
<a href="#">Mr. Rawson</a>
</div>
</div><p style="color:#2E64FE; margin-right:39px;">.</p></div><
<div class="isaac"><p style="Margin left;auto: Margin-right:auto;">    
This Website is Created by Isaac Sybrandy, For reasons Given to me by
Mr. Rawson Of Conway School. This wesbite is Meant to host all of 7th
grades Health Education Videos and is put here for The Younger grades
to Watch and Learn about health and have some Fun at the same time. You
can either watch all of the videos at once, (Below,)
or watch then seperately, one at a time.(Farther Below.) </p><br>
<center>Main Video.</center>
<br><br><br><p style="Float:left;">Video 1</p><p style="margin-
left:48%;">Video 2</P><p style="float:right;">Video 3</p></div>
</body></html>
```

the "Video 3" text is off the div, even though in the code is inside it. What I'm trying to achieve are 3 different columns that I can insert videos into. I can't seem to accomplish this when one column is lower than the others, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: upload it in [JSFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you after something like this?

```css
.isaac {  
  padding: 4px;
  margin-right:2%;
  margin-left:2%;
  background-color: #2E64FE; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.videos{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.video{
  flex-basis: 30%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="isaac">
  <p>This Website is Created by Isaac Sybrandy, For reasons Given to me by Mr. Rawson Of Conway School. This wesbite is Meant to host all of 7th grades Health Education Videos and is put here for The Younger grades to Watch and Learn about health and have some Fun at the same time. You can either watch all of the videos at once, (Below,) or watch then seperately, one at a time.(Farther Below.)</p>
  <center>Main Video.</center>
  <div class="videos">
    <div class="video">Video 1</div>
    <div class="video">Video 2</div>
    <div class="video">Video 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```